Can "Diese" sometimes be used as "she" in German sentences?
This is the sentence I am asking about.

Diese macht sich oft Sorgen um ihre Mutter.

For context, the whole section is

„Das Radfahren hält mich fit", sagt sie zu ihrer Tochter. Diese macht sich oft Sorgen um ihre Mutter. Aber sie wird ihre Mutter jetzt öfter besuchen.

It gets translated as "She is worried about her mother." But I'm really struggling to understand how this construction works. It sounds like normally the worried person is the subject.
Linguee gives an example sentence for this construction:

Der Bürgermeister macht sich Sorgen um die Umwelt. The mayor is concerned about the environment.

So from all of this, I surmise that for some reason "diese" just gets translated as "she". But when I search the question "can diese sometimes mean she in german" or any such variety of search engines (or even this site), I find that this exact question has never been asked, which leads me to believe that I horribly misunderstand the initial sentence and its translation. In fact, many of these particular questions about grammar (e.g. when can an infinitve be used as the subject of a sentence in German?) prove fruitless for some reason.

They do many times. To me it is not okay that they use nonliving pronoun for living beings, but the context has shown, their intent is pretty okay. Interpret this "diese" as if it would be an abbreviation of "diese Leuten". A lot of unclarity what Germans write or say, are actually pretty clear only abrreviated.

@peterh, your misconceptions are not helpful.

The context is important here. You want to replace "diese" with "sie", so let's try that:

... sagt sie zu ihrer Tochter. Sie macht sich sorgen ...

The word "sie" can refer either to the mother or to the daughter. Additionally, the word "sie" was already used in the previous sentence to refer to the mother, so the first impression would be that the second "sie" also refers to the mother. Using another pronoun avoids this confusion.
In this case the content of the next sentence, that "she" is worried about her mother is an argument against the second "she" referring again to the mother, but no necessarily. It might also mean the the mother is worrying about her own mother, the grandmother of the daughter, so that depends on more context than is given here.

It may be worth mentioning that this kind of thing does not exist in English; you'd have to hope that the listener is able to correctly guess who "she" is referring to, or rephrase with additional information, for example "She, the daughter, is concerned about her mother. German resolves this "pronoun overload" by using a demonstrative pronoun as an alternative. Since there's no similar construction in English, translating word for for word from German won't work. Note that this issue has nothing to do with the "sich Sorgen machen" phrase.

If the sentence wasn't about persons or in a formal context, maybe "the latter" would work as a translation of "diese", making it clear that it refers to the daughter and not to the mother. But in the case at hand it would probably not considered appropriate.

@RHa: "the latter" works just fine if it's about people, and works better in a formal context than in an informal one.

To answer the question let us start with a simple phrase:

This is my daughter. She is 25 years old.

The "she" reflects back to "my daughter". It would be (grammatically, perhaps not stylistically) possible to replace "she" with "my daughter" directly.
Now, suppose there are two possible targets of this reflection:

This is my wife and my daughter . She (??) is 25 years old.

It is not clear to what the "she" reflects to, "my wife" or "my daughter". And since, without context, either the wife or the daugther could be 25 not even the age is any clue.
This is as far as it gets in English, the recipient of the message is either left to guess or the speaker would have to rephrase, e.g.: "she, the wife, is 25".
In German there is a remedy to this: "diese" and "jene". Both mean basically "this", but with a different scope, like "the one" and "the other" or (for things) "the former" and "the latter".

Das ist meine Tochter. Diese ist 25 Jahre alt.

Here, "diese" is slightly unidiomatical (but not wrong), because the target of the back-reference is clear. Here one would normally use "sie" (she) instead and the use of "diese" would be grammatical overkill. Once we have several possible possible targets of the reference, though, things become different:

Das ist meine Frau und meine Tochter. Diese ist blond, jene hat braune Haare.

"Diese" refers to the nearer one of two possible back-references, "jene" refers to the one farther away. Notice that "nearer" and "farther" here do not refer to physical but grammatical distances! In the above example "diese" refers to the next "eligible noun", which is "daughter", "jene" to the one farther away. Because "Frau" was placed first in the previous sentence, this is "farther away" from "diese" and "jene". So, here the daugther is blonde and the wife has brown hair.
Also notice that the order in which "diese" and "jene" is used doesn't matter:

Das ist meine Frau und meine Tochter. Jene ist blond, diese hat braune Haare.

Here, "jene" still refers to the "eligible target farther apart", hence, the "Frau" and "diese" to the nearer one. Now the wife is blonde and the daughter brown-haired.
Coming back to your own example:

[...], sagt sie zu ihrer Tochter. Diese macht [...].

You have two possible back-references, "sie" and "Tochter". "Diese" refers to the nearer one, hence "Tochter". Would you replace "diese" by "sie" it would become unclear if the daughter or the mother is meant by that.
You may, for additional information, refer to this thread and this thread
Addendum:
All the commenters who know it better should direct their critizism to (just a few  out of many) this web site:

Die räumliche/zeitliche Entfernung kann sich auch auf den erstgenannten und letztgenannten Sachverhalt innerhalb eines Textes beziehen. Dabei bezieht sich „dieser“ auf den zuletzt erwähnten Aspekt und „jener“ auf den ersten.

or this one:

Dieser, diese, dieses express (place or time) proximity and jener, jene, jenes express (place or time) distance.

Furthermore, be sure to downvote what I wrote, because I got it all wrong and I don't have a source as good as gut feeling on my side.

"Das ist meine Frau und meine Tochter. Diese ist blond, jene hat braune Haare." Your explanation sounds logical, but I'm not convinced that diese/jene are consistently used that way. As an (Austrian) native speaker, that sentence would still be ambiguous to me.

As a native speaker I'd be utterly confused. This doesn't sound natural to me at all.

Das sind meine Frau und meine Tochter, surely?

And I think youd have to at least do it as @Heinzi did and have to have "diese" before "jene", to simply make it flow correctly, having "diese" used after "jene" makes it sound even stranger.

@Heinzi: see addendum.

@infinitezero: you are absolutely right. I can't compete with "doesn't sound".

@TonyK: only if you address them as a sort-of group: "the two over there are..."  In singular the expression is a elliptical shortening of "das ist ... und [das ist] ...".

@bakunin: Thanks for the addendum (I didn't downvote, btw). Regarding your first source: Yeah, that seems to be plain wrong (or at least highly unusual), I'll gladly "direct my critizism" to it. :-) The example given in the link is only non-ambiguous because bishops preach and presidents talk. Place proximity is idiomatic, so using "dieser" and "jener" while pointing first to a near person and then to a person farther away is fine.

@Heinzi: I could quote other sources but they would be equally wrong: may I ask you to downvote my misleading answer, therefore.

@bakunin Language is what people speak; do not become defensive if (presumably native speakers as well as presumably yourself) say "it doesn't sound right". I had the same feeling as Heinzi and found the mother/daughter example equally ambiguous. (Perhaps because it can be read as a parallel construct: "Mutter/Tochter -- diese/jene".) You did good in quoting sources -- we are all here to learn. The parallel construct would probably require "erstere/letztere", I suppose. (Ah yes, you present the "jene/diese" which makes it parallel. Much better to me.

Also note that any possible ambiguity a reader may wrongly perceive is precluded by referring to the mother directly with "Mutter" -- so none of us native speaker, I suppose, needed to read those two sentences twice.

Last not least I cannot help but note the irony that bakunin, of all people, so adamantly refers to the rules. "Herr Direktor!" That's less Bakunin than Engels ;-).
